# 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' error during SQL Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a history table like so:

```
PersonId    FromDate    EntityId
1           2011-08-01  
1           2012-03-02 
1           2014-02-15
2           2015-03-02
3           2012-01-01
3           2012-10-05
```

I have the following tables as well.

**Family**

```
PersonId   AccountId  FamId   FromDate    ToDate      
1          500        A01
1          200        C01
2          400        B01           
3          600        A01                  2012-10-04
3          700        A01     2012-10-05
```

**Missacct**

```
AccountId   SendingEntityFieldId
500         24
200         64
400         24
600         70
700         24
```

The following query returns **NO** records:

```
select f.personid
   from family as f
   where f.famid not like 'C%'
     and (f.todate is null or f.todate >= getdate())
   group by f.personid
   having count(personid) > 1
```

In other words, there are no persons who are actively tied to more than one account at a time.  This query also returns no results:

```
with paccounts as (select f.personid, m.SendingEntityFieldId
   from Family as f
   join Missacct as m on m.AccountId = f.AccountId
   where (f.Todate is null or f.Todate >= GETDATE())
     and f.FamId not like 'C%')
 select personid from paccounts group by PersonId having COUNT(personid) > 1
```

Again, the idea here is that NOT getting more than 1 row per person.

However, when I try to update EntityId in the history table with the following SQL update, I get the error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

```
update PersonHistory set SendingEntityId = 
  (select ma.SendingEntityFieldId 
   from Family as f 
   join Missacct as ma on f.AccountId = ma.AccountId 
   where f.FamId not like 'C%' 
   and (f.Todate is null or f.Todate >= GETDATE()) and f.PersonId = PersonId)
```

It seems as though I should be getting a 1 to 1 match between each record in the history table and the associated record in my subquery.  I don't understand how I can be getting more than 1 value when I've already proved with my previous queries that I'm not getting more than 1 row per person back in my subquery.

(Incidentally, I also tried the following update and it returned the same error)

```
with paccounts as (select f.personid, m.SendingEntityFieldId
 from Family as f
 join Missacct as m on m.AccountId = f.AccountId
 where (f.Todate is null or f.Todate >= GETDATE())
 and f.FamId not like 'C%')
update PersonHistory set SendingEntityId =  
  (select pa.SendingEntityFieldId 
   from paccounts as pa where pa.PersonId = PersonId)
```

Am I missing something?

**Update**

I tried the following update using joins rather than subqueries:

```
update PersonHistory
  set SendingEntityId = ma.SendingEntityFieldId
  from PersonHistory as ph
  join Family as f on ph.PersonId = f.PersonId and f.FamId not like 'C%' and  (f.Todate is null or f.Todate >= GETDATE())
  join Missacct as ma on f.AccountId = ma.AccountId
```

**Update 2**

I tried the following query and got back a record for each PersonHistory record and every one had a 1 in the tot_finds column.  Am I somehow not comparing apples to apples?

```
select ph.personid, (select COUNT(*) from Family where PersonId = ph.personid 
and FamId not like 'C%' and (Todate is null or Todate >= GETDATE())) as tot_finds
from PersonHistory as ph
```

Comment: First off I would stop using subqueries in update statements. Try doing it with joins instead. Then you can more easily check  the results too.

Comment: your queries aren't equivalent, since your test "return no records" have `having` clauses which can REMOVE the rows causing your error. obviously you ARE getting multiple rows returned from the subquery - mysql doesn't spit out that error just because it's having a bad hair day.

Comment: @HLGEM see my update.  Using joins did not see to help

Comment: You do need to correlate your subquery. `where pa.PersonId = PersonHistory.PersonId`. The other poster who noted that same point has deleted his answer.

Comment: a suggestion: Start with Select * From PersonHistory and look at record count. Add in the second join to family and look at record count. Is it what you expected? If not, why? Do the same for the 3rd join. Is your record count what you expected? If no, why. If this doesn't reveal the issue, I like to dump the records into excel (or you can do a derived table query) to see what records are causing the double-up to happen. Unfortunately without your data, it will be hard for us to help. Gotta slog through this.

Comment: @Jeremy -- Thanks for your help on this.  I tried what you suggested.  I did my first query of PersonHistory and got back 130,796 rows.  I then added the Family table with the associated where clause and got back 130,646 rows.  A little odd since the error indicates that I'm getting duplicate rows -- you'd think there would be an increase.

Comment: @RHarris some could be missing, and some could be duplicated.

Comment: @Jeremy -- I tried running the same series of queries against my live data rather than test data.  In this case, the query of PersonHistory and the query of PersonHistory with a join on Family both gave back the same number of results -- 128,445.  However, if I try the update it still gives the same error.

Comment: @RHarris and also the join on missacct?

Comment: @RHarris also make sure you reference the aliased table name in the update statement: Update ph...

Comment: @Jeremy -- Yes, on the live data, I also added the join on missacct and got the same number of records -- 128,445.  Also, please note my new Update #2.  It seems like this would be an accurate test to ensure that I'm only getting a one to one match between person and my joins.  (I also ran that same code with a join on missacct as well and I still get 1 in tot_finds column of all the rows)

Comment: I got it!  Apparently there is a trigger enabled on the table that I was trying to update.  The error I was getting was in regards to the trigger not in regards to the sql statement that I was trying to run.  @Jeremy, thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: glad you got it. sometimes these things are tricky!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error I was getting was a result of an active Trigger on PersonHistory table.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this:

```
update P 
set SendingEntityId =  ma.SendingEntityFieldId 
--select  p.SendingEntityId,  ma.SendingEntityFieldId, *
   from PersonHistory  p
  JOIN  Family as f  on f.PersonId = P.PersonId
   join Missacct as ma on f.AccountId = ma.AccountId 
   where f.FamId not like 'C%' 
   and (f.Todate is null or f.Todate >= GETDATE())
```

When you run the select embedded in the comments, you will probably see what the record problem is and then you can fix the update properly if need be. It is entirely possible the join is giving you multiple records with the same personid and SendingEntityFieldID in which case the subquery won't work but the join will  or you may need to add a where clause to get exactly the right record.

Comment: I'm dealing with over 130,000 records in the history table, so doing a select of the query (without the update) still makes it impossible to tell where I might be getting a duplicate.  Any ideas?

Comment: @RHarris did you try the solution? your original query attempts to set one value to all values in your resultset, which is impossible.

Comment: @HLGEM Change update PersonHistory to Update p since you aliased the table.

Comment: @HLGEM -- I was able to narrow this down by doing a group by on the non-update query.  Apparently I history records that have the same personid and fromdate.  However, this still doesn't make sense as each history record has a unique id so fromdate shouldn't really matter with the way the query is defined.

Comment: @Jeremy -- Yes, I tried the solution provided by HLGEM.  I also used the alias as you suggested.  I'm still getting the same error.